# Converting a pandas dataframe to a list of entries

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe from a numpy array.

```
matrix = scipy.sparse.rand(5, 3, density=0.2, format='lil')
array = numpy.array(matrix.toarray())
users = {5: 0, 10: 1, 15: 2, 20: 3, 25: 4}
games = {1: 0, 4: 1, 6: 2}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=users.keys(), columns=games.keys())
```

What I need now is to get a list from that dataframe, where each cell from the matrix is represented as a tuple of the following format:

```
userID, gameID, value
userID, gameID, value
userID, gameID, value
...
```

to use it with http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#load-custom

Are there any efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Yes there are but without your own trialcode it becomes difficult to let you know if yours is more efficient than others.... By posting your attempt you either are informed by commenting or via a posted answer your question is answered. Add your trail code below your current question information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape first:

...and add column for 3 levels `MultiIndex` and convert it to `tuples`:

```
L = dataframe.stack().to_frame('a').set_index('a', append=True).index.tolist()
```

...or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in dataframe.stack().reset_index().values]

print (L)

[(5, 1, 0.8797632578062221), (5, 4, 0.0), 
 (5, 6, 0.8996885724198237), (10, 1, 0.0), (10, 4, 0.0), 
 (10, 6, 0.0), (15, 1, 0.0), (15, 4, 0.07758205674008478), 
 (15, 6, 0.0), (20, 1, 0.0), (20, 4, 0.0), (20, 6, 0.0), 
 (25, 1, 0.0), (25, 4, 0.0), (25, 6, 0.0)]
```

If want only non `0` values only filter it by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in dataframe.stack().reset_index(name='a').query('a != 0').values]
print (L)

[(5.0, 1.0, 0.87976325780622211), 
 (5.0, 6.0, 0.8996885724198237), 
 (15.0, 4.0, 0.077582056740084782)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
for row in dataframe.itertuples():
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        l.append((row.Index,col, dataframe.loc[row.Index,col]))
```

you can iterate over each row and then each column to append the resulting tuple to a list. On my test this was faster than the previous answer, probably depending on the number of rows and columns you have.

```
%%timeit
l = []
for row in dataframe.itertuples():
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        l.append((row.Index,col, dataframe.loc[row.Index,col]))
```

594 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
L = dataframe.stack().to_frame('a').set_index('a', append=True).index.tolist()
L = [tuple(x) for x in dataframe.stack().reset_index().values]
```

2.25 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

as requested, here the timings for 1000 rows:

```
matrix = scipy.sparse.rand(1000, 3, density=0.2, format='lil')
array = numpy.array(matrix.toarray())
index = list(range(1000))
dataframe= pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=index)


%%timeit

l = []
for row in dataframe.itertuples():
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        l.append((row.Index,col, dataframe.loc[row.Index,col]))
```

17 ms ± 38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit -n 100
    L = dataframe.stack().to_frame('a').set_index('a', append=True).index.tolist()
    L = [tuple(x) for x in dataframe.stack().reset_index().values]
```

5.08 ms ± 16.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Can you add timings for 1000 rows?

Comment: @jezrael sure. i added them to my answer. unsurprisingly your re-index-method scales way better.